# Area preserving & conformal diffeomorphism is isometry

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry, analysis, differential-geometry

Let $\phi: S \to \bar{S}$ be a diffeomorphism between two surfaces in $\mathbb{R^3}$. A map is *conformal* if for all $p \in S$, and $v_1, v_2 \in T_p(S)$ (the tangent plane) we have
$$\langle d\phi_p(v_1), d\phi_p(v_2) \rangle = \lambda^2 \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle_p$$
for some nowhere-zero differentiable scalar function $\lambda$. A map is *area-preserving* if the area of any region $R \subset S$ is equal to the area of $\phi (R)$.
Now the problem is

> Prove that $\phi$ is an isometry if $\phi$ is area-preserving and conformal.

I can clearly see that there is a counter example for the only if direction, but I am not sure how I can proceed with the proof for this statement.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can clearly see that there is a counter example for the only if direction" ? Isometry $\implies$ conformal and also the coefficients of the first fundamental form match, thus area is also preserved!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: If $\phi$ is conformal and area-preserving, and if $dA$ and $d\bar{A}$ denote the respective area forms of $S$ and $\bar{S}$ (in the metrics induced by the embeddings in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$), then for every region $R \subseteq S$,
\begin{align*}
\iint_{R} \phi^{*} d\bar{A}
& = \iint_{\phi(R)} d\bar{A} && \text{change of variables} \\
&= \operatorname{area}(\phi(R)) \\
&= \operatorname{area}(R) && \text{$\phi$ is area-preserving} \\
&= \iint_{R} dA.
\end{align*}
Use the fact that $\phi$ is conformal to express $\phi^{*} d\bar{A}$ in terms of $\lambda$ and $dA$, then use the facts that $\lambda$ is continuous and $R$ is arbitrary to consider what happens if $\lambda^{2}$ is not identically equal to $1$.