# How to show that an area-preserving conformal map is an isometry?

Tags: differential-geometry

There is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179786/area-preserving-conformal-diffeomorphism-is-isometry), but the sole answer did not make much sense to me, especially from the context of classical differential geometry.

Let $S,\bar{S}$ be regular surfaces. Let $F:S \rightarrow \bar{S}$ be an area-preserving conformal map. Let $\phi:U \rightarrow S, \bar{\phi}:\bar{U} \rightarrow \bar{S}$ be parametrization of $S,\bar{S}$ respectively. How can I show that $F$ is an isometry?

**What I've done:**

Let $E,F,G$ be the coefficients of the first fundamental form of $S$ under $\phi$. Let $R \subset S$ be a region. I know that $A(R)=\int \int_Q \sqrt{EG-F^2}dudv=A(F(R))=\int \int _\bar{Q}\sqrt{\bar{E}\bar{G}-\bar{F}^2}dudv$, where $Q=\phi^{-1}(R),\bar{Q}=\bar{\phi}^{-1}(F(R))$. I also know that $\sqrt{EG-F^2}=\lambda^2 \sqrt{\langle dF(\phi_u),dF(\phi_u)\rangle \langle dF(\phi_v),dF(\phi_v)\rangle - \langle dF(\phi_u),dF(\phi_v)\rangle^2}$, where $\lambda$ is the proportion function induced by the conformity of $F$.

I do not know where to go from here.

Answer (score 4):

This is just linear algebra and all the calculus here just muddies the water. If $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix that is conformal, then $A=cR$ for some nonzero scalar $c$ and rotation matrix $R$. You can check this first by seeing that if $\{e_1, e_2\}$ is the standard basis, then $Ae_i=c_i v_i$ for some orthonormal basis $\{v_1, v_2\}$ and some scalars $c_i$; then show $c_1=c_2$ by considering the angle between $e_1$ and $e_1+e_2$ and, correspondingly, their images.

Now the fact that $A$ preserves area tells us that $\det A = c^2 = 1$. Now conclude that $A$ is an isometry — a rotation or the composition of a rotation and a reflection.